# mmaping multiple anonymous pages in c

Tags: c, mmap, segmentation-fault

I mapped two anonymous pages in memory and then access the second page as below:

```
    int* map = mmap(NULL, 8 * 1024, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED |
                    MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int a = map[4096];
```

where the page size is 4096 (I verified this) but this throws SIGSEGV.  I tried using `madvise(map, 8 * 1024, MADV_WILLNEED)` and using the `MAP_POPULATE` flag in mmap, but these didn't help.  What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What size are `int`s in your environment? You've allocated 8K *bytes*, but if `int`s are at least 2 bytes wide, `map[4096]` will be past the 8KB mark.

Comment: This was my problem.  I addressed it in my answer but didn't see your response since the page hadn't refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is I declared `map` as an `int*`, so referencing `map[4096]` looked for the value at location `map + 4 * 4096`, assuming `int`s are 4 bytes long, and this is obviously outside the range I reserved with `mmap`.